# Kotlin lazy property depending on another property initialized in init

Tags: kotlin

I have the following class in Kotlin:

```
class Example {
    val name: String

    val lazyVar: String by lazy {
        name + " something else"
    }

    init {
        name = "StackOverflow"
    }
}
```

I get the following error when I use `name` in the lazy initialize block of `lazyVar` (even though `name` is initialized in the `init` block) :

> Variable 'name' must be initialized

A solution is to initialize the variable in another method:

```
class Example {
    val name: String

    val lazyVar: String by lazy {
        initLazyVar()
    }

    init {
        name = "StackOverflow"
    }

    private fun initLazyVar(): String {
        return name + " something else"
    }
}
```

This technique works but is there a way to keep the compacity of the inline lazy block instead of relying on an external function?

Comment: Try changing the arrangement by calling init first before lazyVar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
class Example {
    val name: String

    init {
        name = "StackOverflow"
    }

    val lazyVar: String by lazy {
        name + " something else"
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that worked, thanks!
I'm wondering why though. Is this a bug or the order of declaration matters?

Comment: Exactly, the name must be evaluated before lazy block is evaluated.